scanf doesn't recognize numbers correctly
I was trying to make a program that makes a triangle comprised of numbers that are imputted. For example, if I input a string 123 the output should be the following.
1
12
123

I tried to implement it with the following code:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char s[501];
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    for (int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++) {
        for (int j=1;j<=s[i];j++) {
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

However, the output was the following (the input was 123):
12345...4849
12345...484950
12345...48495051

Any ideas? Thanks

1 (an integer) is different than '1' (a character). In most current computers (ASCII based ones) the character '1' has the integer value 49.

There's no encoding where 1 == '1'. The loop condition j <= s[i] will not work as you expect.

I understand. Thanks!!

BTW, never discard the return value of scanf() - without that, you have no idea whether its conversion(s) succeeded or not.

The problem doesn't lie in scanf(). In this loop:
for (int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++) {

s[i] gets converted to decimal value of the ASCII character (there
are other systems too like EBCDIC but most likely you're not using
it). You can see it in man ascii - 1 is 49, 2 is 50 and 3 is 51. You
need to convert this number to a number that's the same as the string
value of the character:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char s[501];
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    for (int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++) {
        for (int j=1;j<=s[i]-'0';j++) {
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
$ ./main
123
1
12
123

Also, you don't need to include <string.h> and <stdlib.h> and the
correct prototype of main() should be int main(void).

The problem is here where you print the character code (in decimal):
            printf("%d", j);

We should be dealing in characters throughout; that means using %c conversion:
    for (int i = 0;  s[i] != '\0';  i++) {
        for (int j = 0;  j <= i;  j++) {
            printf("%c", s[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

We can avoid the inner loop by printing just an initial substring of s, using %s conversion:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[501];
    if (scanf("%500[^\n]", s) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0;  s[i];  ++i) {
        printf("%.*s\n", i+1, s);
    }
}

Now there's no assumption that the input characters are digits, and we can print a triangle of any characters.
